# Center TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

how do i center this? You can see the Code next to the Emulator [image]

```
              Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 120,
              child: TextFormField(
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                ],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                controller: controller,
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  alignLabelWithHint:  true,
                  floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
                    labelText: lableText,
                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I added code Snippet so you can see it better :)

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: Yeah sure, its done

Comment: Use hinttext instead of label text to center it. I dont know how you could do it with labeltext

Comment: try using `label` as @seyyed javad described

Answer (score 0):

1. delete labelText and Use label instead.
2. give Text to label as child.
3. wrap label with Center.

```
  TextFormField(
    .
    .
    .
    label: Center(
      child: Text('In jahren'),
    ),//center
  ),//TextFormField
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
SizedBox(
              width: 120,
              child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'In jahren',
              ),
            ),)
```